# Why do the javascript video buttons not work?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm only trying to add a mute/unmute button, I followed a couple of tutorials, wrote the same code but it doesn't seem to be working.
Also, if any one of you feels particularly generous today, could you please show me how to make a single button that mutes, and when clicked again, unmutes the video sound?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      <div>
        <video id="vid"autoplay muted loop></video>
        <div class="controller">
            <button onclick="muteVideo()" type="button">Mute sound</button>
            <button onclick="unmuteVideo()" type="button">Enable sound</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      
      <script>
        var my=document.getElementById("vid");
            function playVideo(){
                my.play();
            }
            function muteVideo(){
                my.muted = true;
            }
            function unmuteVideo(){
                my.muted = false;
            }
    </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      <div>
        <video id="vid"autoplay muted loop></video>
        <div class="controller">
            <button onclick="muteUnmuteVideo()" type="button">Mute/Unmute sound</button>
           
        </div>
      </div>

      
      <script>
        var my=document.getElementById("vid");
            function playVideo(){
                my.play();
            }
            function muteUnmuteVideo(){
                my.muted = !my.muted;
            }
            
    </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This Code Works fine

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div>
        <video id="vid" width="400" controls>
            <source src="../../Downloads/Bohemian Rhapsody _ Muppet Music Video _ The Muppets_360p.mp4"
                type="video/mp4">
            <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            Your browser does not support HTML video.
        </video>
        <div class="controller">
            <button onclick="muteVideo()" type="button">Mute sound</button>
            <button onclick="unmuteVideo()" type="button">Enable sound</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        let my = document.getElementById("vid");
        const playVideo = () => {
            my.play();
        }
        function muteVideo() {

            console.log("hello");
            my.muted = true;
        }
        function unmuteVideo() {
            my.muted = false;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just Add your video src and click on button to mute & unmute

Comment: i added the src on my file, i didnt write it here since the video wouldnt be visible anyway, but should edit the post